# NSData to NSMutableData conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsmutabledata

is there some way to convert an `NSData` object, into an NSMutableData one? Basically I am using `NSJSONSerialization` which basically takes some JSON data I receive and transforms it into an `NSData` object instance. Is there anyway to then transform this into an `NSMutableData` object instance? I need to do this because later on, I will be spawning some threads and within the code blocks I provide, I would like to change the value of the Data object. I can't do that if its `NSData` but I can if its `NSMutableData`.

Comment: NSMutableData *mutableData = [receivedData mutableCopy];

Comment: I have no idea how you intend to hang the NSData. Normally you would serialize the received data to dictionaries or arrays and work with them.

Comment: @vikingosegundo this is a good point.  Here's a line of code i use in my project.  NSMutableDictionary * leaderBoardJsonData = (NSMutableDictionary)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

Answer (score 6):

```
NSMutableData * data = [NSMutableData dataWithData:jsonData];
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: oops, my bad :) fixed

Comment: If I call the dataWithData command on the same NSMutableData object instance multiple times, will it then re-write the data each time since its mutable?

Comment: you don't call `dataWithData:` on an object. you call it on the class.

Comment: @vikingosegundo said it, call it on the actually NSMutableData class, not the instance of the class (data)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
NSData *data = ...;
NSMutableData *mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
```